# How to detect deposits using Web3.js?

Tags: web3js, payments

I've a service and I'm accepting Bitcoin using Bitcoind. I want to accept Ethereum too by running an ethereum node.

I want to generate an address for each customer, which RPC command should I call? When I assign a user with a new address in my DB, I want to listen for new transactions.

I'm asking this because I couldn't found a documentation or tutorial about this.